# autoincrement number with synchronization support

Tags: java, concurrency

I need to  generate unique auto increment id which will started from 0. below is my use case.
I have two fields. one is prefix and another one is number.
while save the each record auto increase the number and concatinate with prefix and save.
prefix # test-
number # 0
before saving concatenate two values like (test-0).
any one help me out from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use AtomicInteger or AtomicLong class which is released with java 7 :

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Examples:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/atomicinteger.html

> The AtomicInteger class provides you with an int variable which can be read and written atomically, and which also contains advanced atomic operations like compareAndSet(). The AtomicInteger class is located in the java.util.concurrent.atomic package.
>
> The most common use of the AtomicInteger is to handle a counter that is accessed by different threads simultaneously.The java.util.concurrent. The Atomic package provides very useful classes that support lock-free and thread-safe programming on single variables.

```
private static AtomicInteger at = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

By passing 0 you can initialize it with 0 (default). after that, you can concatenate prefix (static variable) and concat them example:

```
test+at.getAndIncrement(); // getAndIncrement() - Atomically increments by one the current value.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does Atomiclong support concurrent users?

Answer (score 3):

Ignite is open source support sequence generator using prefix.Ignite sequence id generator.[Link](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/id-generator)

Or 
you can create concurrentHashMap with key as your prefix and AtomicInteger as value.You need some kind of persistence because if your server restart in-memory value should not start from zero.

Comment: Since which version Ignite supports sequence generation? What is other most valuable features for this framework?

Comment: We are using latest version in our project I think Id generator support from initial version.Similar to Hazelcast it support most distributed data structure like Queue ,set ,AtomicType(I.e AatomicLong),distributed lock etc.